# Simple Select INNER JOIN statement - SQL query ERROR

Tags: mysql

I have a simple MySQL statement that keeps showing an error.

`type` is an column in table `ps_product_custom_statistics_weekly` and i would like to select only the value from `type` where it has an value of `all`.

```
SELECT `cat`.`brand_name`
FROM `ps_product_brand` AS `cat`
INNER JOIN `ps_product_custom_statistics_weekly` AS `cat_p` 
ON `cat_p`.`id_product` = `cat`.`id_product`
WHERE `cat_p`.`type` LIKE `%all%`
AND `cat_p`.`rank` <= 16;
```

**Error msg** :

> `#1054 - Unknown column '%all%' in 'where clause'`

(i dont understand why it tells me this, im using `cat_p.type` to select column and `LIKE %all%` to get string from that column, please help)

Table:

**ps_product_custom_statistics_weekly**

```
  product_id        type            rank
+-------------+--------------+------------------+
|      1      |    weekly    |       20         |
+-------------+--------------+------------------+
|      2      |      all     |       10         |
+-------------+--------------+------------------+
```

Thanks

Comment: Use the correct quote characters, backtick (`) for identifiers, single quotes  (') for string literals.

Comment: please tag correctly, it should be only MySQL, not sql server also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using backticks instead of single quotes. Use it like this:

```
WHERE `cat_p`.`type` LIKE '%all%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give quotes to `like` condition like below,

```
SELECT `cat`.`brand_name`
FROM `ps_product_brand` AS `cat`
INNER JOIN `ps_product_custom_statistics_weekly` AS `cat_p` 
ON `cat_p`.`id_product` = `cat`.`id_product`
WHERE `cat_p`.`type` LIKE '%all%'//Change quotes
AND `cat_p`.`rank` <= 16;
```

Backquotes **`** should not work for string manipulation in mysql query

Answer (score 0):

Solution must be

```
SELECT `cat`.`brand_name`
FROM `ps_product_brand` AS `cat`
INNER JOIN `ps_product_custom_statistics_weekly` AS `cat_p` 
ON `cat_p`.`id_product` = `cat`.`id_product`
WHERE `cat_p`.`type` LIKE '%all%'
AND `cat_p`.`rank` <= 16;
```

**As Like value must be in '' not in ``**